# jquery <Script> tag added in the Sharepoint Masterpage is not rendered in Popup page

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, master-pages, script-tag

i have added the script tag `"/_layouts/Memento/jquery.tablednd.js"`  along with few other script tags in the SharePoint master page under `"head"`. I am calling a popup page by doing `window.open(test.aspx)`. In this page the above "script" is not rendered. If i check the view source am not able to find the tablednd.js which helps to perform drag and drop.

Normal pages the tablednd is available.I don't want to write a JavaScript code to add this script to popwindow at runtime. Kindly help me to place the "script" inside the master page in a proper way so that it will be rendered by the popup window also,

Comment: test.aspx also have the same master page ?

Comment: Yes ir is. If i open this page normally like response.redirect(test.aspx) it renders the script but if i open the same page as popup then the problem occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you are adding the script lines to the correct masterpage.
In you popup.aspx, check the top lines to see if it is using the v4 system master page